# Magento2 - Default datetime value add column

Tags: magento2, sql, column, database-schema

I'm using magento Magento2.3.4, I tried to add new column with datetime type and default value of current datetime like this:

```
$columns['created_time'] = [
                             'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
                             'nullable' => true,
                             'comment' => 'Created Time',
                             'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT
                           ];
```

but i always got an error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid
>   default value for 'created_time'

Answer (score 1):

Change your type to timestamp,

```
$columns['created_time'] = [
      'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
      'nullable' => true,
      'comment' => 'Created Time',
      'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT
];
```

Comment: i need the type in `datetime` format

Answer (score 0):

```
<column xsi:type="datetime" name="created_at" on_update="false"
                nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" comment="Created Time"/>
```